# Display is not updated until exiting calling method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6

I am trying to display a wait state with wait indicator within a text label.

```
-(void)progressTask {

    while (taskInProgress == YES) {

        if (progressStepChanged == YES) {
            progressStepChanged = NO;
            switch (progressStep) {
                case E_PROGRESS_NONE:
                    break;

                case E_PROGRESS_WAIT:
                    HUD.mode = ProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
                    HUD.labelText = @"Please Wait";
                    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Transaction in Progress";
                    HUD.labelTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    HUD.detailsLabelTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
                    break;

                case E_PROGRESS_DECLINED:
                    HUD.mode = ProgressHUDModeCustomView;
                    HUD.labelText = @"Transaction Result";
                    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Declined";
                    HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Cross.png"]];
                    HUD.labelTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    HUD.detailsLabelTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
                    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
                    break;

                case E_PROGRESS_COMM_LOST:
                    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
                    break;

                case E_PROGRESS_APPROVED:
                    HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]];
                    HUD.mode = ProgressHUDModeCustomView;
                    HUD.labelText = @"Transaction Result";
                    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Approved";
                    HUD.labelTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    HUD.detailsLabelTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        usleep(100);
    }
}

-(void)startProgressManager:(UIViewController*)viewController {
    if (HUD == nil) {
        HUD = [[ProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:viewController.navigationController.view];
        [viewController.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
        HUD.delegate = self;
    }
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(progressTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
```

There is an observer to each parameter in the "progressTask". The ProgressHUD class is responsible for the creation of the wait indicator within an information text. The "progressTask" is launched as a background task :

```
-(void)showWhileExecuting:(SEL)method onTarget:(id)target withObject:(id)object animated:(BOOL)animated {
    methodForExecution = method;
    targetForExecution = target;
    objectForExecution = object;    
    // Launch execution in new thread
    self.taskInProgress = YES;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(launchExecution) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    // Show HUD view
    [self show:animated];
}


-(void)show:(BOOL)animated {

    if (animated && animationType == ProgressHUDAnimationZoomIn) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotationTransform, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f));
    } else if (animated && animationType == ProgressHUDAnimationZoomOut) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotationTransform, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f));
    }
    self.showStarted = [NSDate date];
    // Fade in
    if (animated) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30];
        self.alpha = 1.0f;
        if (animationType == ProgressHUDAnimationZoomIn || animationType == ProgressHUDAnimationZoomOut){
            self.transform = rotationTransform;
        }
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else {
        self.alpha = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

The issue is when I call the "startProgressManager" from the ViewController class, the wait indicator is shown only after the method is exited (after sleep(3)).

```
-(IBAction)recallBtnPress:(id)sender {
    progressManager = [ProgressManager new];
    [progressManager startProgressManager:self];
    progressManager.progressStep = E_PROGRESS_WAIT;
    sleep(3);
}
```

Is there something wrong in my implementation, or can anybody provide another code for the wait indicator display while code is running.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know what sleep, usleep and while do right?

Comment: usleep is used to not block the processor and sleep is used to simulate execution of code. The idea is to have a waiting indicator displayed while code is code is running. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sleep on the main thread and don't update UI components off the main thread.

The general pattern is switch to a separate thread of execution for a background task, when updates are needed switch to the main thread to update the UI.

Just out of curiosity is there a reason you are using `NSThread` instead of [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a very basic senario of switching to a background thread, then switching to the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // THIS CODE RUNS IN THE BACKGROUND

    // Your data crunching. You can call methods on self, if it's thread safe.

    // AFTER PROCESSING
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        // SWITCH BACK TO THE MAIN THREAD

        // Update the UI.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have no idea about the Grand Central Dispatch, is it more convenient to use it? What  is the main thread in this case? Excuse me I am a beginner in iOS developments. Thanks.